Does the Firestore Admin SDK for Node.js retry individual reads and writes after transient errors?
Does the Firestore Admin SDK for Node.js automatically retry individual reads and writes (doc.get(), doc.set()) after transient errors such as network errors?
This seems to be the case for the other implementations of the Firebase Admin SDK as stated below, however this page also states that the guidance doesn't apply to the Node.js Admin SDK.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/error-handling#automatic-retries
There doesn't seem to be an error handling guide for the Node.js SDK specifically.
It is also stated that transactions are automatically retried by the Firestore SDKs, but it's not clear whether this applies to individual read/write operations that are not part of a transaction, or if this only applies to the client SDKs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#transactions_retries
Is there any documentation etc. that confirms the retry/error handling behaviour specifically for the Node.js Firestore Admin SDK?
ie. will the following code automatically retry after network errors:
try {
  const snap = await getFirestore().collection("collection").doc("doc").get()
  // process data
} catch (e) {
  // handle non-transient errors
}

or would the following code with manual retry logic be necessary:
try {
  const snap = await getFirestore().collection("collection").doc("doc").get()
  // process data
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof FirebaseError && (e.code === `unavailable` || e.code === `aborted`)) {
    // retry after transient errors
  } else {
    // handle non-transient errors
  }
}

